# Qt signal slots and memory alocation

Tags: c++, qt

I have an application which communicates with an external application and this controls a devices. When new data have arrived in this device, my application should send an "answer" to this device. The communication with the external application is done with some callback functions and I use signals/slot to deliver the correct message to the callback. 
My problem is that after the original signal returns, the application crashes with SIGSEGV error. As far as I know this error refers to failure in memory. As the external application could dealocate /destroy/corrupt the original data, could you please tell me if this a safe way to use signal/slot mechanism? Or this could have caused a SIGSEGV? Bellow, I am posting a code snippet as example:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{ 
    notifierData = new QWinEventNotifier(HandleData);
    objectItem = new ObjectItem();
    connect(notifierData,SIGNAL(activated(HANDLE)),SLOT(newDataSlot(HANDLE)));
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(objectData(int, QByteArray)), objectItem, SLOT(dataChangedSlot(int, QByteArray)), Qt::QueuedConnection) ;
}
void MyClass::newDataSlot(HANDLE)
{
    DataType data;
    GetDataFromExternalCallback(&data);
    QByteArray bytearrayData(data.str);

    emit objectData(data.TC_Index, bytearrayData);
 }

void ObjectItem::dataChangedSlot(int index, QByteArray data)
{
    emit dataChanged(index, data);
}

DeviceInterface::DeviceInterface()
{
    Init(Line1);
}
void SetObjectItem(ObjectItem *anObjectItem)
{
    objectItem = anObjectItem;
    if(objectItem != NULL)
    connect(objectItem, SIGNAL(dataChanged(int, QByteArray)), this, SLOT(newDataRecevied(int, QByteArray)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
}

void DeviceInterface::newDataRecevied(int index, QByteArray data)
{
    QString messageToDisplay = "Reply Answer";

    if(objectItem != NULL)
    {
        objectItem->updateDeviceDisplay(index, messageToDisplay);
    }
}

bool DeviceInterface::updateDeviceDisplay(int index, QString text)
{
    //Line1 is class member: char Line1[20]
    sprintf_s(Line1, 20, "%s", UnicodeToCodePage(1253,text.toStdWString().c_str()));
    SendDataWithExternalCallback(&Line1);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, for example there is from Qt:
    void QApplication::focusChanged(QWidget *old, QWidget *now)

Comment: Have you tried running a debugger?

Comment: The problem seems coming from `objectItem` ... you are using an object  that is not initiated in your `MyClass` class nor to your `DeviceInterface` class ..

Comment: Sorry for that, I just forgot to add it in this sample. In the original code, it is initialized. I have added the initialization. About the debugger, this is a problem, as it crashes anly in the computer which has the actual device and does not have debugger. I have produced a dump files and this shows that that the crash is inside QtCore.dll. I don't know the excact line as I don't have pdbs for qt dlls

Comment: What I have also noticed is that if I separate the call of UpdateDeviceDisplay from this sequence of actions and send it  e.g. after pressing a button, the crash does not occur.

Comment: _segmentation fault_ results from invalid memory access, this happens in many cases, like when accessing an object before allocating memory for that object ... just make sure all objects are memory allocated; in your constructor `MyClass::MyClass()`  check where you allocated memory for `objectItem` .. your code does not show that.

Comment: Mohammad Kanan  thanks for noticing. As stated before this is not the original code, but a part of it. The object is initialized in the way I have edited the code now

Comment: @Aditya That's just wrong...